# Aren't questions about keeping something in the refrigerator that don't specify for how long too generic to be answered?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

Are questions like "Is it safe to keep [X] in the refrigerator?" too generic to be answered?

For example, see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/376/is-it-safe-to-put-rice-in-refrigerator
I guess that most things are not safe if they are kept in the refrigerator for too long time, and that most things are still safe to be kept in the refrigerator for few hours.

Comment: Do you have an example of one that's too generic? And, moreover, wouldn't it be part of the answer to specify the length of time to which it was safe?

Comment: @Grace Note I added the link to a question. The problem I see with such questions is that you could always reply with "yes/no," and you would be correct most all of the times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd have to say yes, that qualifies for a NARQ closing.

The more appropriate formulation of the question, as evidenced by countless [storage-lifetime](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage-lifetime) questions already in the system, is *"how long is it safe to store X (in the refrigerator)?"*  I can't think of any food that immediately develops bacterial colonies as soon as you put it in the fridge.

If I hear no objections in the next little while then one of us will close it (feel free to vote to close as well).